# how to solve problems: zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost:4200/login 404 (Not Found)

Tags: mysql, angular, express

I want to do a simple login function for my page.I use Angular-MySQL-Express-Sequelize for this page.
When I do a POST to login, it always tell me 
zone.js:3243 POST http://localhost:4200/login 404 (Not Found) 
I don't know what is that means and how to solve it.

This is my customer.service.ts

```
export interface Details {
  username: string;
  password: string;
  age: number;
  type: string;
}
interface TokenResponse {
  token: string;
}
export interface TokenPayLoad {
  username: string;
  password: string;
}
public login(customer: TokenPayLoad): Observable<any> {
    const base = this.http.post('/login', customer);

    const request = base.pipe(
      map((data: TokenResponse) => {
        if (data.token) {
          this.saveToken(data.token);
        }
        return data;
      })
    );

    return request;
  }
```

////

This is my login.component.ts

```
credentials: TokenPayLoad = {
    username: '',
    password: '',
  };

  constructor(private customerService: CustomerService, private router: Router){}
  ngOnInit() {
  }

  login() {
    this.customerService.login(this.credentials).subscribe (
      () => {
        this.router.navigateByUrl('/customer');
      },
      err => {
      }
    );
  }
```

////
This is my backend login function

```
exports.login = (req, res) =>{
    Customer.findOne(
        {where: {
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
            }
        }).then(customer => {
        if(req.body.password = customer.password){
            let token = jwt.sign(customer.dataValues, secret_key, {
                expiresIn: 1400
            })
                    res.json({token: token});
        }
        else{
            res.send('user not exists');
        }
    })
        .catch(err => {
            res.send('error is ' + err);

    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using Angular-CLI to create your project. You will need to proxy your API (if you want to use the same port ie 4200).

The article below shows you how to configure proxy with Angular CLI

https://itnext.io/angular-cli-proxy-configuration-4311acec9d6f

Comment: Thank you very much ! I added config.json file but it seems no reaction.
the terminal told me: 
[HPM] GET /login ~> http://localhost:8080
[HPM] Rewriting path from "/login" to ""
[HPM] GET /login ~> http://localhost:8080

and my nodejs server has no response on terminal. Is that means I still miss anything?

Comment: you also need to run `ng serve -proxy-config proxy.conf.json` assuming you have your config as `proxy.config.json`. If you have your config set correctly, your nodejs server will respond.

Comment: That's what I did, but page is ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE. I have closed proxy port on Chrome
"/login/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
      "^/login": ""
        }
    }

Comment: please share your proxy.config.json

Comment: {
    "/login/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
      "^/login": ""
        }
    },
    "/customer/*": {
      "target": "http://localhost:8080",
      "secure": false,
      "logLevel": "debug",
      "changeOrigin": true,
      "pathRewrite": {
      "^/customer": ""
        }
    }
  }

Comment: have you tried using POSTMAN or CURL to test your nodejs express app before?